# Unity, Android Resovler, JDK Path won't update to new directory

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, java-home

I know this question was asked a couple of times before, but I just cant get it to work for a couple of days now.

I just opened a project with a different version of Unity, (my fault), the JDK still pointing at the old directory and it just won't update no matter what i do !

[Here's an idea of what's going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf5VT.png)

I've tried installing the JDK from their website and pointing to it, nope

I've updated the environment variables pointing to the Unity OpenJDK, nothing new.

I've followed some threads suggesting to uncheck then check again the JDK part in "External tools", nothing new.

Cmd `echo %JAVA_HOME%` is pointing to the right location

I've even deleted UnityHub and UnityEditor and reinstalled them, nothing has changed.

Is there like a temp file somewhere storing the information of the location of JDK somewhere maybe i can change it manually?

or what else can I try?

I assume if i install the same version of the currently pointed location,
and put it in the same path it might work, but there must be a different way!

Comment: check if some of your paths contains white spaces (I am assuming that you're talking about Windows), that they typically are found in the username. P.ej: `C:/Users/Slim Hidri/...` sometimes Windows struggles with those paths, so be careful to correctly scape them

Answer (score 0):

I just did the poorest solution, just copy the new editor's OpenJDK and create a fake directory exact same as the problem pointing to it, and just paste it there. If there's any better solutions just let me know !